# jQuery "Back-to-top" arrow jumps to top of page before scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a static html/css/js webpage which has a jQuery Back-to-Top button that appears at the bottom after the page has scrolled down 20px. The arrow, scrolling, etc all work great, except for one super-annoying bug that's bothering me:

When I click on the Back-to-Top arrow, the **arrow itself** jumps up to the top of the screen for literally a second, and then it returns to it's proper spot and the page scrolls like it's supposed to. Here's a gif screenshot. Watch it carefully; the arrow jumps very quickly: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B243NwSBmRtdUDRvczZMQ0p6QVE

And here's the HTML:

```
...</nav>
<a href="#" id="toTopBtn">
    <img src="img/arrow-up-white.png" alt="Back to Top" title="Back to Top"/>
</a>
<section ...
```

And the CSS:

```
/** BACK TO TOP **/
#toTopBtn {
    display: none; position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px; right: 30px;
    z-index: 98; padding: 15px; 
}
#toTopBtn img {width:80%;}
#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555; /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
```

And the Javascript/Jquery:

```
/******* BACK TO TOP BUTTON *******/
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

// Show "Back to Top" button when user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        $("#toTopBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        $("#toTopBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
$("#toTopBtn").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("section#home").offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

Any tips for how to fix this?

Comment: do you have a live link to your site?

Comment: http://studentweb.mga.edu/shira.shkarofsky/ - It's my **in-progress** portfolio ;) so don't expect everything on it to work yet... (The arrow error shows there, though)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this one on many sites, all working well so give a try.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
      $('#toTopBtn').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('#toTopBtn').fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $('#toTopBtn').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
/** BACK TO TOP **/

#toTopBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 98;
  padding: 15px;
}

#toTopBtn img {
  width: 80%;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="toTopBtn">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Back to Top" title="Back to Top" />
</span>
<pre>
  a
  a
  a
  a
  a
  
   a
  a
  a
  a
  a
   a
  a
  a
  a
  a a
  a
  a
  a
  a a
  a
  a
  a
  a
  b
  b
  b
  b
  b
    b
  b
  b
  b
  b
  b  b
  b
  b
  b
  b
  b  b
  b
  b
  b
  b
  b  b
  b
  b
  b
  b
  b2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  2
  b
</pre>
```

Comment: I really like the jQuery code you gave. Definitely much cleaner and smoother than what I had. :) Unfortunately, even with that code, the arrow still does that little jump when it's clicked...

Comment: @Sh306 I checked your site, it is a keydown/mousedown/onmousedown on the toTopBtn cause it, if you press the button don't release, it is float on top, check all your css related to that button and js code? keydown mousedown

Answer (score 0):

Here you have solution for Up + Down.

```
    <span id="toTopBtn">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Back to Top" title="Back to Top" />
    </span>
    <span id="toBottomBtn">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Back to Bottom" title="Back to Bottom" />
    </span>

    <style>     
        #toTopBtn {
          display: none;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 20px;
          right: 30px;
          z-index: 98;
        }

        #toTopBtn img {
          width: 80%;
        }

        #myBtn:hover {
          background-color: #555;
          /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
        }

        #toBottomBtn {
          display: none;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 20px;
          right: 75px;
          z-index: 98;
        }

        #toBottomBtn img {
          width: 80%;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
      $(function(){
          $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
              $('#toTopBtn').fadeIn();
            } else {
              $('#toTopBtn').fadeOut();
            }
          });

          $('#toTopBtn').click(function() {
            $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop: 0
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          });

          $(window).scroll(function() {
            if (($(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop()) == 0) {
              $('#toBottomBtn').fadeOut();
            } else {
              $('#toBottomBtn').fadeIn();
            }
          });

          $('#toBottomBtn').click(function() {
            $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop: $(document).height()
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.